# How to get navbar to not display until a user logs in? [Done]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am struggling with getting my NavBar to not display/show until a user has logged in (received a token). I know you can set it up using a ternary but I am not able to get one to function. If another option besides a ternary works I am okay with that.

```
import Auth from './Auth/Auth';
import Sitebar from './Home/Navbar';
import ReviewIndex from './Reviews/ReviewIndex';
import Navigation from './Home/Navigation'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  const [sessionToken, setSessionToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('token')){
    setSessionToken(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  }
}, [])

const updateToken = (newToken) => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', newToken);
  setSessionToken(newToken);
  console.log(sessionToken)
}

const clearToken = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
  setSessionToken('');
  window.location.href="/" 
}

const protectedViews = () => {
  return (sessionToken === localStorage.getItem('token') ? <ReviewIndex token={sessionToken}/>: <Auth updateToken={updateToken}/>)
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Sitebar sessionToken={sessionToken} clickLogout={clearToken}/>
      <Navigation sessionToken={sessionToken} />
      {protectedViews()}
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

the way i would approach this is i would use the turnary operator to conditionally render it. so here you are setting the session token as soon as the component renders and you are only doing it once.

so heres what you could write to conditionally render this.

```
{sessionToken ? "Put Jsx here that you want to render if they are authenticated" : "Put Jsx here to render if they are not authenticated"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// css file

.navigation {
    visibility: 'hidden';
    // or 
    display: 'none';
}

// component
<Navigation className={sessionToken ? 'navigation': ''} />
```

It really depends what you want to do. lizardcoder's solution won't mount the component at all until the user is logged in. My solution will hide it, but it will mount. If you don't want to initialize anything in Navigation until the user is logged in, lizardcoder's is the right way to go. If you just want to hide it, css is a good way to go.